# React select - different labels for dropdown list and for input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

Is it possible (by default) to specify one label for react-select dropdown options and have another label
be displayed in input field after one of the dropdown options has been selected.

For example, if I have following object:

```
{label: "David Smith", selectLabel: "Dave",  value: 1}
```

Is it possible by default to have it so `label` is displayed in the dropdown list and after I make a selection that `selectLabel` is displayed in input field?

By saying "default" I mean if there is a prop somewhere or something that would allow me to specify values for dropdown list and input field separately?

So basically I'm looking to get something like this:

[image]

and after selection occurs I want "Dave" (and not "David Smith") to be shown in the input field:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `formatOptionLabel` to achieve this result.

```
<Select
   name="color"
   options={colourOptions}
   formatOptionLabel={(option, { context }) => {
     /* context can be either `menu` or `value`
        menu - dropdown
        value - value displayed
     */
     return context === 'menu' ? option.label : option.color;
   }}
/>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-61286833-fhqrp)

[Docs](https://react-select.com/props)